# How to edit the "Edge 3d" filter output properly with InkScape?

Tags: inkscape, effects, mask, filter

I am currently creating a bevel effect with Inkscape. I found that the easiest and coolest way to do it was using the "Edge 3d" filter. Not willing to redo the bevel effect now.

Anyway, the way I did it was by selecting the image/object and the applying the filter to the image/object. The output was perfect. However, I edited the image/object size and tried to edit the bevel effect aswell, getting the following output:

[image: Bevel]

It seems to be some sort of "mask" that should be linked to the object and failed to. What I am trying to do is to edit this "mask" so the effect can be applied properly. Am I doing forgetting something here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Edge 3D" Extension duplicates the selected `Path` object to create a `clipping path`. This mask is applied to a group of smaller paths that have a Gaussian Blur `Effect`. You can see this relationship clearly if you look at the XML Tree in `Edit > XML Editor`.

Unfortunately, this effect is not "live". Any changes to the original path are not applied to the "3D effect"-path. It would be easiest to delete the bevel effect and create a new one. If you really want to do it manually, you can edit a `clipping path` without unclipping by using the node-edit tool:

1. Select the whole "effect" object with the select tool
2. Switch to the `Node-edit` tool
3. **Make sure "Show clipping paths" is selected**
4. Edit the clipping path and effect nodes

[image: How to edit a clipping path with the node tool]

Comment: I'll start by saying, this is the coolest answer I've ever received. Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful and illustrative. I actually wanted to know does the effect work, which you did explain as well. Thanks again.